# Force BSOD in VBS

Tags: vbscript

So, I'm trying to create a script for a YouTube video, and I want to force a BSOD using vbs or batch without killing any processes. Could I just call some kind of BSOD process?

Trying to kill csrss.exe freezes the system for about 10 seconds before BSODing. I want an instant BSOD.

I actually have no idea how to do this code, so that's why I'm asking for code, or at least a little hint

Comment: [Maybe related](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/forcing-a-system-crash-from-the-keyboard).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/forcing-a-system-crash-from-the-keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Causing a BSOD on demand without controlling a device driver (which requires the WHQL logo) and without smashing with cess is not possible to my knowledge as that would mean that the operating system is bugged. You can force a BSOD by enabling the [manually imitated crash feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0xe2--manually-initiated-crash). The feature is designed to stimulate a bug in a device driver to dump the kernel in order to take the crash dump and perform part morten analysis.

In vbs it should be

```
WshShell.SendKeys "^%{F12}"
```

Comment: how to do this in vbs?

Comment: For what I know, the configuration can be done via registry editor, see the attachment document, but requires rebooting the first time. To initiate the crash, you need to send the keyboard command via the `SendKeys`. I have updated the answer.